# dll error flycapture

Tags: c++, dll, flycapture

I'm using Visual studio 2010 and I  use a point gray camera. I use the flycapture libs and dll's to capture the video stream in my application. I use the FlyCapture2.dll, FlyCapture2d.dll and libiomp5md.dll (all 32 bit). My application compiles and links with the static libraries perfectly and in release mode it also runs perfectly. However, in debug mode I get the following error:
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150002). click OK to close the application.

I think that there is a problem with the dynamic libraries of flycapture. I use the lastest version of flycapture but I am unable to fix this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Look in the Windows event log for the side-by-side error details.  You'll probably need to contact the vendor for support.

Comment: Problem is, the debug dll of FC2 depends on the debug visual c++ runtime dlls, which are not distributed and not available for download either.

Comment: These dlls come from VC++ 8.0 (2005) so if you don't have VS 2005 installed, you don't have them, period. I suppose even if you did, there would probably be a version mismatch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, it seems that the .pdb file is missing in the flycapture sdk for Flycapture2d.dll. My quick solution was to use the FlyCapture2.dll even under the debug mode.

Comment: I had the same, but only on deployment computer. On development all was fine. Using FlyCapture2.dll is solution for me.